# How do I globally register ionic storage using the CordovaSQLiteDriver in Vue 3

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, pinia

I created a Vue 3 Ionic Typescript app. I installed @ionic/storage and the localforage CordovaSQLiteDriver driver. The docs say I need to do the following:

```
const store = new Storage({
  name: 'localDb',
  driverOrder: [CordovaSQLiteDriver._driver, Drivers.IndexedDB, Drivers.LocalStorage],
})
await store.defineDriver(CordovaSQLiteDriver)
await store.create()
```

Where do I do this? I put it in main.ts, but I can't use await in main. My goal is to be able to use the store variable in all of my Vue views and components, and also in my Pinia stores. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file storage.ts put your storage code there and export it. In my case i did something like this:

```js
import {Drivers, Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import CordovaSQLiteDriver from 'localforage-cordovasqlitedriver';


const storage = new Storage({
    driverOrder: [CordovaSQLiteDriver._driver, Drivers.IndexedDB, Drivers.LocalStorage]
});

storage.create().then(store =>{
    console.log("VALUE: ", store)
    console.log('Storage created')
})

storage.defineDriver(CordovaSQLiteDriver).then(()=>{
})

export default storage
```

the use the exported storage in your script tag:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import storage from "@/<PATH_TO>/storage";

onMounted(async ()=>{
  const test = await storage.get('test');
  await storage.set("my-key", data)
})

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
```